# How to display the interface name with tshark

Tags: tshark

I am using tshark to diagnose an asymetric route problem. I am filtering the traffic so only src/dest to a specific ip is being captured, but I would like to display a field that shows which interface the traffic is going in/out on so I can see the impact as I work with route tables.

With Wireshark I can get partway there by displaying the MAC address using **Hardware dest addr** and **Hardware src addr**, but in TShark I can't find that filter.

Can anyone suggest a way to display the NIC name, or MAC address with TShark?

Here is the tshark command I have tried:

```
tshark -i eno1 -i enp5s0 -T fields -E header=y -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e _ws.col.Protocol -e _ws.col.Info -Y "ip.addr==10.10.10.30"
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution.
It turns our that the fields displayed in Wireshark have direct correlations to fields you can display in tshark. So you search under Frame in the [Wireshark doco](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/#section_f) and all becomes clear. My issue was not seeing the correlation between the doc and the Wireshark UI to see what I could do on the command line.

All I had to do was add **-e frame.interface_name** or **-e frame.interface_id**

Answer (score 2):

To find out about field names, you can also use the `json` or `pdml` output formats by passing `-T json` or `-T pdml` to `tshark`. You'll see all the dissected fields in the capture with the same name as you can use in display filters or select with `-e` for the `-T fields` format:

```
[
  {
    "_index": "packets-2021-10-09",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "layers": {
        "frame": {
          "frame.interface_id": "0",
          "frame.interface_id_tree": {
            "frame.interface_name": "wlp3s0"
          },
          "frame.encap_type": "1",
[...]
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="pdml2html.xsl"?>
<!-- You can find pdml2html.xsl in /usr/share/wireshark or at https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/raw/master/pdml2html.xsl. -->
<pdml version="0" creator="wireshark/3.4.8" time="Sat Oct  9 10:20:13 2021" capture_file="file.pcap">
<packet>
  <proto name="geninfo" pos="0" showname="General information" size="52">
    <field name="num" pos="0" show="1" showname="Number" value="1" size="52"/>
    <field name="len" pos="0" show="52" showname="Frame Length" value="34" size="52"/>
    <field name="caplen" pos="0" show="52" showname="Captured Length" value="34" size="52"/>
    <field name="timestamp" pos="0" show="Oct  9, 2021 10:19:24.034789189 BST" showname="Captured Time" value="1633771164.034789189" size="52"/>
  </proto>
  <proto name="frame" showname="Frame 1: 52 bytes on wire (416 bits), 52 bytes captured (416 bits) on interface wlp3s0, id 0" size="52" pos="0">
    <field name="frame.interface_id" showname="Interface id: 0 (wlp3s0)" size="0" pos="0" show="0">
      <field name="frame.interface_name" showname="Interface name: wlp3s0" size="0" pos="0" show="wlp3s0"/>
    </field>
    <field name="frame.encap_type" showname="Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)" size="0" pos="0" show="1"/>
```

In `wireshark`, you can select the field you're interested in, right-click and Copy -> Field Name:

[image: screenshot of field name copy]